# How to get flag based on country value?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have a select-option country list and I need to get from database flag based on these values.

Here is my controller:

```
         if(count($data['user']['career_path']) > 0)
            {
                $careerpath =  array_reverse($data['user']['career_path']->toArray());
                $data['company'] = $careerpath[0]['company'];
                $data['industry'] = $careerpath[0]['industry']['industry'];
                $data['department'] = $careerpath[0]['department']['department'];
                $data['job_title'] = $careerpath[0]['functions']['function'];
                $flags = \App\Country::lists('flag', 'id');
                $flag = $flags->get($careerpath->location);
                dd($flags);


            }
```

So, here is the logic :

I have a table for countries called `countries`.

```
1.id --- 2.country --- 3.flag
```

That is my table where I have all my countries.

Here is how I use this country list in my view:

```
{!! Form::select('location',$country_id ,$user->country->id, ['class' => 'js-example-basic-single']) !!}
```

where  `$country_id`

```
$data['country_id'] = \App\Country::lists('country','id');
```

When I pick something from my select form, like Greece or Italy, in database is saved the id of country from that list.( 20 or 21)

How I get that value in view?Like here:

```
@foreach($user->career_path as $careerpath)
{{$careerpath->location}}
@endforeach
```

The problem is I need to pick `country` and `flag` values based on `id` from `location` field.

So, if my value is 20, I need to get the `country` name and `flag` value from table `countries` based on the value ( id 20 ) from {{$careerpath->location}} . `$careerpath->location` now returns me id of the country, I need to get, based on that, country name ( from countries.country) and flag value( from countries.flag).

Comment: Did I understand you right, you want to add a flag next to the _Italy_ or _Greece_ in your select menu, or is it something else. Can't quite understand.

Comment: first of all remove the <> tag in option value italy

Comment: Yes. I already have the code for every country in database, but these are saved in table `countries`, column id, country and flag. In this value `{{$careerpath->location}} I only have the name of countru`

Comment: @Aroon sorry, I wrote it wrong.

Comment: so `$careerpath->location` is a country that matches the name of a country in `countries` table?

Comment: @lagbox I edited my question . `$careerpath->location` now returns me id of the country, I need to get, based on that, country name ( from countries.country) and flag value( from countries.flag).

Comment: @zlatan please check again my question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$flags = App\Country::lists('flag', 'id');
```

Then you can get the flag by the id:

```
$flag = $flags[$careerpath->location];
// or
$flag = $flags->get($careerpath->location);
```

Inside your loop:

```
{{ $flags->get($careerpath->location) }}
```

Comment: Hey, now I get `ErrorException in ViewProfileController.php line 645:
Trying to get property of non-object` , which is `$flag = $flags->get($careerpath->location);` .  Please check my controller again, I edited it.

Comment: the loop part is in your blade view ... the loop you are using where you need to get the flag for the location of the careerpath

Answer (score 1):

If you have a country in `$careerpath->location` then you can direct retrieve flag data:

```
if(!empty($careerpath->location)){
     $flags = \App\Country::where('id', $careerpath->location)->select('flag')->first();   
     dd($flags);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but I have already received a good answer :)